# Managing a set of class file dependencies with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

I'm working with a third-party vertical industry app whose distributes their Java-based application as a set of class files (as opposed to a JAR file). For the purposes of development I am looking for suggestions on how best to manage and reference the set of class files. I've been wondering if it is a good idea to just JAR them up myself, poke around at Maven to see if it can help out, etc... I want to manage them as a package much like I would a Ruby gem or NuGet package. How are others managing dependencies for their Java apps?

Comment: Maven or Ant/Ivy or Gradle etc. Either jar them up, or keep them in an isolated directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can add the *.class files to your project dependencies in Eclipse:

```
Configure build path -> libraries -> add class folder
```

It would be the simplest possible solution.

However, if you're working in a team and all of you relies on this third-party code, than I'd opt for creating a jar file from all those *.class files. It would be easier to maintain.

If the library is continuously changing / updating and you need some sort of more centralised place to manage different versions of it, than I'd jar it anyway and put it in your Maven repository (or go with the Apache Ivy).

HTH.

Comment: This is a team environment and multiple projects will depend on these libraries, that's why I was thinking originally that JAR'ing it might be the way to go even though the vendor ships loose class files.  I've been doing some digging about Maven vs. Ivy and there doesn't seem to be a clear winner there though.

Comment: Because there isn't a all-or-nothing winner :-) Maven is often used in big projects, where ant (+ Ivy) is preferred for simple projects. IMHO I would go with Maven, as I've tried to use Ivy some time ago (4 months?) and it was even more painful than Mvn. Just try which one suits you needs better and go for it! :-)